# Vim plugins: calling a function in insert mode inserts function signature into buffer rather than actually calling the function

Tags: vim

For example, with VimOrganizer:

`* one`

Then, when I hit Enter, this is what ends up in the buffer:

`* oneorg#tbl#kbd_cr()`

Comment: Show us your mapping: `imap <Enter>`

Comment: `i  <CR>        &@org#tbl#kbd_cr()<SNR>17_AutoPairsReturn`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're mixing an expression mapping with a standard mapping.

`org#tbl#kbd_cr()` is a function that returns keystrokes to an expression mapping (`:help map-expr`). `<SNR>17_AutoPairsReturn` is a (script-scoped) mapping itself. To be able to concatenate the two, use an intermediate mapping for the function:

```
:inoremap <expr> <SID>org-mapping org#tbl#kbd_cr()
:imap <Enter> <SID>org-mapping<SNR>17_AutoPairsReturn
```

Comment: Yep, this seems to be the case.  To fix the issue, I just replaced the offending plugin (Auto-Pairs) with another that offers the same functionality (delimitMate).

Answer (score 0):

At least for the .vimrc, there are different modes to map a key, for example, imap for insert mode, nmap for normal mode.  If you map something with imap, it needs to be aware that it's in insert mode and generate commands appropriately, for example:

```
:inoremap <F2> <C-R>=expand('%:p:h')<CR>
```

See [Mapping keys in Vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_%28Part_1%29) for me info.